# Nokogiri problems parsing xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

In my controller I have:

```
xml_doc.xpath('//locale').map do |i|
Thing.create!(:name => i.xpath('englishName').inner_text, :lang => i.xpath('representation').inner_text)
end
```

The xml doc is: http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

The problem is that the lang column is set to:

```
af_ZAar_ARaz_AZbe_BYbg_BGbn_INbs_BAca_EScs_CZcy_G...
```

for each element created.

The problem:
[image]

Comment: stanard looks like a typo. also, would you mind spelling out what you are trying to achieve and what you get?

Comment: I want to get the representation for each locale and englishName(which I get correctly). Save all the locales in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the issue is that the `representation` isn't at the same level as `englishName`:

```
xml_doc.xpath('//locale').map do |i|
  englishName = i.xpath('englishName').inner_text

  # Or just ".//representation", or if there may be multiple codes, you
  # need to be even more clever about determining which to use.
  representation = i.xpath('codes/code/standard/representation').inner_text

  puts "#{englishName} - #{representation}"
end
```

Outputs (truncated):

```
Thai - th_TH
Filipino - tl_PH
Turkish - tr_TR
Ukrainian - uk_UA
Vietnamese - vi_VN
Simplified Chinese (China) - zh_CN
Traditional Chinese (Hong Kong) - zh_HK
Traditional Chinese (Taiwan) - zh_TW
```

Comment: Shorter alternatives `i.css('representation')`, or `i.xpath('descendant::representation')`.

Comment: @Casper Why use the `descendant` variation when there's `.//`? I'm not a huge XPath person (by choice ;) so I really don't know. I also tend towards being explicit as often as possible, particularly since I don't know the full schema of the FB XML file :/

Comment: No reason. I'm not a huge XPath person either, obviously :)

Comment: @Casper Heh, gotcha. But that's good to know about; I've actually not seen it--I'll look it up. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah good point on the schema, in that sense your solution is the most accurate one.

Comment: @Casper - How may I contact you? :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor change to fix it:

```
xml_doc.xpath('//locale').map do |i|
    Thing.create!(:name => i.xpath('englishName').inner_text, :lang => i.xpath('.//representation').inner_text)
end
```

I changed `'representation'` to `'.//representation'` since `representation` isn't an immediate child of `locale`.  I just tested it and it works perfectly.